# Duplicate records in DevTools network when using Dio packkage

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

**UPDATE:**
It seems to be a bug in devtools. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3607) in DevTools github repo.

---

I use Dio package to send requests. It works well but when I monitor network traffic in DevTools network, it shows duplicate records (or maybe Dio sends each request multiple times!). Here is my Dio configurations:

```dart
static final Dio _dio = Dio()
    ..options.connectTimeout = 10000
    ..options.receiveTimeout = 5000
    ..options.receiveDataWhenStatusError = true
    ..httpClientAdapter
    ..options.contentType = 'application/json';
```

And this is what network tools shows:
[scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuMCe.png)